# python syntax error although syntax is correct

Tags: python, syntax-error

For the following python function:

```
 def startElement(self, tag, attributes): 
        if tag == "artikel":
            print("<tr><td>{}</td> <td>".format(attributes["id"])
        if tag == "preis":
            print("</td> <td>")
        if tag == "lieferant":
            print("</td> <td>")
```

I get the following syntax error:

```
  if tag == "preis":
                   ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have no idea at all what's supposed to be wrong with the syntax here.
Does anybody else know what's up here?

Comment: It's not correct. You are forgetting the closing parentheses in the line above for your `print` function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add a closing parenthesis:

```
print("<tr><td>{}</td> <td>".format(attributes["id"]))
#                                      Missing here  ^
```